# Microsoft SQL Server - Is it possible to perform an arithmetic operation between two specific rows in a table?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do an arithmetic operation between two specific rows of the following table (which you can refer as MyTable):

[image]

To be more clear, my idea is to add a new row to the table on which I am trying to insert the result of dividing all the values in the row where [Account_No] = 1000001509 by all the corresponding values where [Account_No] = 1000001543 and to the value of that division then substract all the corresponding values where [Account_No] = 1000001509 again. For example, for [2022-01-01], it would be: ( 7168000 / 0.987 ) - 7168000, and so on for the following columns...

Is there anyway of doing this in Microsoft SQL Server? I cannot find any useful way so far.

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. we cannot make use of data from a picture. As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Sure, you are right. Thank you very much for the note, I will take it into account for next time

Answer (score 1):

Just join back to the table.

```
SELECT (base.[2022-01-01] / A.[2022-01-01]) - base.[2022-01-01] as [2022-01-01],
       (base.[2022-02-01] / A.[2022-02-01]) - base.[2022-02-01] as [2022-02-01],
       (base.[2022-03-01] / A.[2022-03-01]) - base.[2022-03-01] as [2022-03-01],
       (base.[2022-04-01] / A.[2022-04-01]) - base.[2022-04-01] as [2022-04-01]
FROM MyTable as base
JOIN MyTable as A ON A.Account_Num = 1000001543 
WHERE Account_No = 1000001509
```

Just a note -- the fact you have column names as dates has a bad smell to it.  I suspect your data model is fundamentally broken.

I'd expect the data to be contained in a table like this

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int primary key |
| account_num | int (or string?) |
| occur_date | datetime / timestamp |
| value | float (or numeric) |